# Android DDMS GPS location inserted, but no reaction anywhere in the system

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, ddms

I try to use the DDMS location mockup with a very simple `Log.i()` call in the functions of all LocationListener attributes. When I start the program I get the `Log.i()` message for `onStatusChanged()` in my LogCat, so I think that I registered the listener correctly. But when I put a location into the VM using the DDMS menus in Eclipse I get nothing. No change in LogCat, Console, or inside the VM. As if nothing happened at all.

How can I even start to find the problem?

Here is the code for my simple GPS Event logger:

```
public class gpsActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG="gpsActivity";
    private static TextView label;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged: "+arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: "+arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: "+arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
            }
        };
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2, 0,
                listener);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and here the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypackage.example.gps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".gpsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also as another side note, I am using a German Windows XP and found out that there are problems with GPS packages, because in a German system the number format for 1/2 is not 0.5 but 0,5 which leads to errors in the GPS parser grammar. But also changing my systems number format to English(US) didn't change that I don't get any message, exception or result at all.

Comment: Do you have more than one device connected? DDMS will show all connected devices and you have to select the appropriate one just FYI.

Comment: No device connected. Only VMs from the SDK. DDMS also only shows one device, `emulator-....` and also the according processes.

Comment: Post your code where you setup the listener, that might provide some more insight into your issue.

Comment: @Quintin Robinson Okay, code added.

Comment: Why do you use random strings as your log tags? Do you filter the log by process ID?

Comment: I see setContentView(R.layout.main); at the end of onCreate.. This statement must be just after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: @Octavian Damiean: I was jsut too lazy to write something meaningful. Also it doesn't matter because I just want to find out which event was thrown, right?

Comment: Well since you are logging to the information channel which always gets flooded by a myriad of other messages you should filter either for tags or for process IDs. Your tags should always be meaningful by the way, they were not made for fun. If you just want to find out if a position fix was acquired then just go for a `Toast` message.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean I changed the messages to be somewhat more meaningful. Thank for the advice!

Comment: @Kartik I changed that, which doesn't seem to have an effect on anything. Anyway that `setContentView()` call always confuses me a little. I always put it in the wrong place.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean Before I can get a fix, I need to be able to get any event at all, right? That is the first thing I want to get. A simple `onLocationChanged` event.

Comment: It has a huge effect. You can now remove the `static` modifier from your `TextView` to access it. There is no need to have that `TextView` be static. If you query for `View`s before calling the `setContentView()` method then you will get a `NullPointerException` since your layout file wasn't parsed at that time.

Comment: You can get the other events just as well. Disable the GPS device via the settings and your `onProviderDisabled()` method will be called.

Comment: @erikb let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2519/discussion-between-octavian-damiean-and-erikb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There where 3 problems involved. Because finding all of them took more then 12 hours of pure research time please excuse that I won't even try to find the according sources again.

The problems involved where:

1. You should use `Google API <version>` as target and not `Android <version>` because there are nesssesary things not activated in the latter.
2. You should send the updates via telnet and not DDMS because DDMS creates some uncertain, undocumented and not logged results, especially if you are using a non-US version of Windows.
3. The time zone in your emulator is automatically chosen, but maybe to the wrong locale (as mine is Germany, for example). You can switch it off **inside** a running emulator in the Android settings and also choose your correct locale. This only seems to appear in older versions of Android.

Good luck to everybody who tries his way to this kind of errors!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your device/emmulator is selected in the device menu of DDMS.

EDIT:

Oops. I should have seen these earlier:

You are using `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. In order to receive mock locations from DDMS (and I think also the command line through `geo`), you must register the `GPS_PROVIDER`. Your code works by changing the last line of the onCreate method:

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2, 0,
                listener);
```

`NETWORK_PROVIDER` is signals through the phone network (e.g 3G) or WIFI

Comment: That's a good point, but not the problem. The thing is, if u didn't select a device, u also don't get any LogCat messages at all. So I am sure I selected it properly, because I get LogCat messages. Only for GPS I don't get any.

Comment: it's true, that was wrong. But not in my codebase, just in what I pasted here.

Comment: i see you figured everything out. Be sure to accept your post as the answer so others can see the resolution.